# Keycloak - Docker: How to sends all login logs to stdout including success & failures?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, keycloak, azure-aks, keycloak-services

I want to sends all login logs to stdout including success & failures.

What I see is that, by default, Keycloak sends all login failures to stdout. However, In order to get successful login events, it must be changed to write debug messages to stdout as per this [article](https://www.n-k.de/2020/12/keycloak-events-logging.html).

Excerpt from the above referenced article

> CHANGE THE LOG LEVEL OF THE ORG.KEYCLOAK.EVENTS CATEGORY LOGGER With
> this approach, you add an entry in the logging subsystem of the
> underlying Wildfly configuration. The new entry tells the logging
> subsystem to print all log messages from the package
> org.keycloak.events with DEBUG level and above to the log output:
>
> /subsystem=logging/logger=org.keycloak.events/:add(category=org.keycloak.events,level=DEBUG)

Below is the terraform code that is being used to deploy **keycloak**. Is there something that I can set to in the below code to enable DEBUG level logging?

```
resource "helm_release" "keycloak" {
  repository = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
  chart      = "keycloak"
  namespace  = kubernetes_namespace.keycloak.metadata[0].name
  name       = "keycloak"

  # liveness and readiness probes are enabled by default
  # ref: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/keycloak
  set {
    name  = "replicaCount"
    value = 1
  }

  set {
    name  = "auth.adminUser"
    value = "admin"
  }

  set {
    name  = "auth.adminPassword"
    value = random_password.keycloak_admin.result
  }

  set {
    name  = "proxy"
    value = "edge"
  }

  set {
    name  = "postgresql.enabled"
    value = "false"
  }

  set {
    name  = "externalDatabase.host"
    value = module.keycloak_database.app_db_host
  }

  set {
    name  = "externalDatabase.port"
    value = "5432"
  }

  set {
    name  = "externalDatabase.user"
    value = module.keycloak_database.app_db_user
  }

  set {
    name  = "externalDatabase.password"
    value = module.keycloak_database.app_db_password
  }

  set {
    name  = "externalDatabase.database"
    value = module.keycloak_database.app_db_database
  }

  set {
    name  = "ingress.enabled"
    value = "true"
  }

  set {
    name  = "ingress.ingressClassName"
    value = "nginx"
  }

  set {
    name  = "ingress.hostname"
    value = "account.${local.domain}"
  }

  set {
    name  = "ingress.tls"
    value = "true"
  }

  set {
    name  = "ingress.annotations.cert-manager\\.io/cluster-issuer"
    value = "letsencrypt"
  }

  set {
    name  = "ingress.annotations.cert-manager\\.io/acme-challenge-type"
    value = "http01"
  }

  set {
    name  = "ingress.annotations.nginx\\.ingress\\.kubernetes\\.io/proxy-buffer-size"
    value = "12k"
  }

  set {
    name  = "ingress.annotations.nginx\\.ingress\\.kubernetes\\.io/force-ssl-redirect"
    value = "true"
    type  = "string"
  }

  set {
    name  = "service.sessionAffinity"
    value = "ClientIP"
  }

  set {
    name  = "serviceAccount.automountServiceAccountToken"
    value = "false"
  }

  set {
    name  = "production"
    value = "true"
  }

  set {
    name  = "service.type"
    value = "ClusterIP"
  }

  set {
    name  = "resources.limits.cpu"
    value = "1000m"
  }

  set {
    name  = "resources.limits.memory"
    value = "500Mi"
  }

  set {
    name  = "resources.requests.memory"
    value = "500Mi"
  }

  set {
    name  = "containerSecurityContext.enabled"
    value = "true"
    type  = "string"
  }

  set {
    name  = "containerSecurityContext.runAsUser"
    value = "1001"
  }

  set {
    name  = "containerSecurityContext.runAsNonRoot"
    value = "true"
  }

  set {
    name  = "containerSecurityContext.allowPrivilegeEscalation"
    value = "false"
  }

  # requires write access to fs
  set {
    name  = "containerSecurityContext.readOnlyRootFilesystem"
    value = "false"
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I'd to do is

```
  set {
    name  = "logging.level"
    value = "DEBUG"
  }
```

**Reference:**
https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/keycloak#keycloak-logging-parameters